# Python sqlite query works in terminal but not as exe

Tags: python, sqlite, terminal, exe

I'm writing a Python script that pulls user information from a sqlite db. My query works when I run the script manually in the terminal. But when I run the script as an executable, sqlite returns an operational error.

Code:

```
import datetime
import sqlite3

def get_user_info():

    user_id = input("type the user's id number:")
    # connect with the  database 
    connection = sqlite3.connect('test.db')

    # sql query
    query = '''
    SELECT * 
    FROM c_list 
    WHERE user_id = ?
    '''
    crsr = connection.execute(query, (user_id))
    
    for row in crsr:
        print("Username : ", row[0])
        print("User ID :", row[1])
        print("Book(s) checked out :", row[2])
        print("Date checked out :", row[3])
        print("\n")

    connection.commit()
    connection.close()

    answer = input("would you like to return a book?")
    if answer == 'yes':
        return_book()
    else:
        exit()

get_user_info()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 42, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 24, in get_user_info
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: c_list
[7892] Failed to execute script test
```

Comment: `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: c_list` <-- the error could not be more clear.  Are you certain that the table even exists at the time you run your Python script?

Comment: If you use a relative file path the wrong "test.db" may be opened. Use an absolute path instead.

Comment: You are using a relative path to you database. Depending on your working directory you might open another file or even create a new empty one.

Comment: I tried the absolute path, but I'm still getting the same error. I know the table exists because the script works just fine if I don't run it as an executable. Also, there's one and only one 'test.db' file, so there's no way the script is opening the wrong file.